# SQlite large number separate by commas

Tags: sqlite, number-formatting

I am trying to find a way to format any large number 1000 or more with commas in SQlite.  So, 1000 would be 1,000.  1000000 would be 1,000,000, and so on.

I can easily handle individual cases by changing the numbers to text and then using SUBSTR, but I need a catch all solution that can be done in SQLite.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the function [`printf()`](https://sqlite.org/printf.html):

```
SELECT printf("%,d", col) 
FROM tablename
```

Replace `tablename` and `col` with your table's and the column's name.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e3e033c9817332fa8403383718af6433).